# Finding a solution to make a decent batterypack, that I can install and charge/discharge without having to remove it

Tags: dc, battery-charging, bms

I have a problem with a power delivery circuit for my bluetooth speaker I am planning to build.
I am unable to find a BMS for 4 Cells that would allow me to charge and discharge it through different terminals.

[Here is what I initially bought](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MLVGCNG)

But these BMSs only have 2 Terminals for Charging/Discharging. What I want is a BMS that can charge and discharge, but through different outputs, so I dont have to flip switches all the time when going from use to charging. I have been recommended the BQ24753A Microcontroller in a schematic a fellow user designed. [image: designed circuit]

I am no electrical engineer and just a beginner. As far as i understand I would have to buy the chip and build the other necessary components for it to actually work.I have been told the chip could also help downregulate the voltage from the PCB, but I thought I could just use a dc voltage step-down regulator, since thats more beginner friendly imo. I couldn't find a PCB with the chip that would cover my needs. Maybe I am just looking in the wrong spots.

Is there anything that would help in my specific case?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I don't understand the wish to "charge & discharge at the same time". If you have power to charge with, charge with that and power the device from it also. If you charge and discharge at the same rate, the battery gets worn out, even if left plugged in. Bad phones do this. Good ones turn on without a battery when they're plugged in. If you add the battery, they charge it at the same time.

Comment: @enhzflep Sorry english is not my first language. I made a mistake in the way I explained it. What I want is a BMS that can charge and discharge, but through different outputs, so I dont have to flip switches all the time when going from use to charging. What you described was my initial Idea. I wanted a portable Bluetooth speaker that can run with the power plugged in and will charge its own batteries. I think I am just to unexperienced to actually pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

First, the board you have is called "Protection PCB Board". It is a very important board that makes sure that your batteries will not catch fire or become damaged from overdischarge. However, it cannot charge the batteries by itself. You need a separate charger board for that (or a special AC/DC adapter which is designed for 4S li-ion battery charging)

Second, you don't need any switches or multiple outputs -- as long as you are not drawing too much power, you can connect charger and discharger to the battery at the same time. Here is an example for 1S configuration:

[image: 1s powerbank schematics]

Note that picture is for 1S, and you have 4S -- so you need different parts. Your "li-ion battery charger" board must be able to charge 4 cells, and your DC/DC converter must be power enough for your speaker.

Comment: I do have a PSU attached to a DC-DC buck converter that downregulates the 24V of the PSU to the max 16,8V of the batterypack. As far as I understood the board is there for short and overcharge/discharge protection. Also wiring the PSU in parallel to the 2 Batterybacks should split its 5A current into approx. 2,5 Amps which should be fine for 3200-3400 mAh packs. Wouldn't hooking up the batteries directly to my load cause them to overcharge tho, since the Protection board wont regulate that anymore? The amplifier I have hooked up can draw 100W max. and will take between 9-27V DC.

Comment: The protection board does not regulate anything, all it can do is to trip the circuit open in the bad case and balance cells. It is up to your power supply (DC/DC converter in this case) to limit the current. If your converter has CC mode, you can use it to limit max current, then it will act as charger.